# cpp-netlib how to make such example return over TCP (remove http header)?

Tags: c++, http, boost, tcp

I know there is boost::asio that is made for such stuff but It would be so much easier for me if there was a way to switch between use http and not use http...  (I mean I have 10 services that use http and 4 that use TCP but do quite same stuff (receive http get requests and return TCP messages ) so such function would really help for me)

So lets see an [example of http serrver](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/hello_world_server.html)

```
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/server.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace http = boost::network::http;

struct hello_world;
typedef http::server<hello_world> server;

struct hello_world
{
    void operator() (server::request const &request,
                     server::response &response)
    {
        std::string ip = source(request);
        response = server::response::stock_reply(
                       server::response::ok, std::string("Hello, ") + ip + "!");
    }
};

int
main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " address port" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    try
    {
        hello_world handler;
        server server_(argv[1], argv[2], handler);
        server_.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How to make it return messages with out http response herder?

Comment: Could you expand on your design a bit? It seems quite strange to take a http formatted request but return a response in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use an HTTP library, you might try netcat or other tools that send direct messages over TCP without any particular protocol.